# Check if two users in the same chat

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

I need to be able to get only if there are matches on 2 different user id and match the 'chats_idchats' with the 'idchats'
Query used:

```
SELECT *
  FROM chats_has_usuarios chu
 INNER JOIN chats c
    ON c.idchats = chu.chats_idchats
 WHERE chu.chats_idchats = c.idchats
   AND chu.usuarios_idusuarios = 1
    OR chu.usuarios_idusuarios = 2
```

| chats_idchats | usuarios_idusuarios | idchats | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1 | 8 | 2020-12-15 |
| 8 | 2 | 8 | 2020-12-15 |
| 9 | 2 | 9 | 2020-12-15 |

I want to get

| chats_idchats | usuarios_idusuarios | idchats | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1 | 8 | 2020-12-15 |
| 8 | 2 | 8 | 2020-12-15 |

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM chats_has_usuarios chu
DISTINCT chu.usuarios_idusuarios
INNER JOIN chats c ON c.idchats = chu.chats_idchats
WHERE chu.chats_idchats = c.idchats
AND chu.usuarios_idusuarios = 1
OR chu.usuarios_idusuarios = 2
```

If you want to use with any ids:

```
SELECT * FROM chats_has_usuarios chu
DISTINCT chu.usuarios_idusuarios
INNER JOIN chats c ON c.idchats = chu.chats_idchats
WHERE chu.chats_idchats = c.idchats
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM chats_has_usuarios chu
INNER JOIN chats c ON c.idchats = chu.chats_idchats
WHERE chu.chats_idchats = c.idchats
AND exists(select 1 from chats_has_usuarios abc 
where chu.chats_idchats = abc.chats_idchats 
and chu.usuarios_idusuarios <> abc.usuarios_idusuarios)
```

base on usuarios_idusuarios is the userid

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `exists`:

```
select chu.*, c.fecha
from chats_has_usuarios chu
inner join chats c on c.idchat = chu.chats_has_usuarios 
where 
    usuarios_idusuarios in (1, 2)
    and exists (
        select 1
        from chats_has_usuarios chu1
        where 
            chu1.usuarios_idusuarios in (1, 2) 
            and chu1.chats_idchats = chu.chats_idchats
            and chu1.usuarios_idusuarios <> chu.usuarios_idusuarios
    )
```

Assuming that the same user does not appear twice in the same chat, another option is window functions, if you are running MySQL 8.0 or higher:

```
select chu.*, c.fecha
from (
    select chu.*, count(*) over(partition by chats_idchats) cnt
    from chats_has_usuarios chu
    where usuarios_idusuarios in (1, 2) 
) chu
inner join chats c on c.idchat = chu.chats_has_usuarios 
where chu.cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM chats_has_usuarios chu
INNER JOIN chats c ON c.idchats = chu.chats_idchats
WHERE chu.chats_idchats = c.idchats
AND chu.usuarios_idusuarios = 1
OR chu.usuarios_idusuarios = 2) t1
,

(SELECT * FROM chats_has_usuarios chu
INNER JOIN chats c ON c.idchats = chu.chats_idchats
WHERE chu.chats_idchats = c.idchats
AND chu.usuarios_idusuarios = 1
OR chu.usuarios_idusuarios = 2) t2

where t1.usuarios_idusuarios < t2.usuarios_idusuarios and
and t1.chats_idchats=t2.chats_idchats
```